# ClassCastException java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable при добавлении Object в TreeMap

Tags: java, объекты, treemap

Предположим, что у меня есть `TreeMap` c типом `Object` у ключа и значения. Я хочу положить в `TreeMap` `Object`:

```
TreeMap<Object, Object> treeMap = new TreeMap();
treeMap.put(new Object(), new Object());
```

Данный код выдаст ошибку:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

в методе

```
final int compare(Object k1, Object k2) {
    return comparator==null ? ((Comparable<? super K>)k1).compareTo((K)k2)
        : comparator.compare((K)k1, (K)k2);
}
```

который находится внутри `TreeMap`.

Я понимаю, что если вместо `Object` возьму `String`, `Integer` или любой другой тип, то всё будет нормально. Почему не проходит с `Оbject`-ом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) - коллекция, которая реализует внутри себя [красно-черное дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE). Для этой структуры обязательно, чтобы ключи можно было сопоставить между собой(больше, меньше и эквивалентно). Поэтому для того чтобы положить какой-то объект внутрь, необходимо выполнить одно из условий:

- Ключ должен реализовывать интерфейс [Comparable](http://Comparable)
- При создании [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) передать в [конструктор](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-) имплементацию интерфейса [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), которая сможет сравнить между собой объекты ключа

В вашем же случае класс [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) пытаются привести к [Comparable](http://Comparable), и программа на этом падает, т.к. это невозможно. [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) и много еще каких классов из стандартной библиотеки уже реализуют этот интерфейс, и поэтому с ними всё отрабатывает.